# How to make it so you can only use a command every 30 minutes?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Self-explanatory in the title.

Comment: Apply [`discord.ext.commands.cooldown`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown) decorator to your command.

Answer (score 0):

You can add discord.ext.commands.cooldown and then set the rate(1) and set per(30) then type(user), This will set a cooldown of 30 min after it has been used once by a user.

Check the documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown